# Count Function in php for JSON object

Tags: php, facebook

In php, would the function count work also on a JSON object? Will it return the number of elements in the object? Or does this function only work for an array?

```
count($varJSONobject);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923149/a-php-count-of-the-number-of-items-returned-in-json-request

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate. though the answer might be the same, the question is different. 
And why is it a POSSIBLE duplicate? If you think that it is, say so, or do you no tknow the answer to my question? If you do, please answer it. If you don't you can just remain quiet, you don't have to downvote it just because you are not sure. Thank you

Comment: I didn't downvote your question. And adding "possible duplicate" links to questions is fairly common on here. It's nothing personal.

Comment: @Lucy Weatherford: When you use the `close` function, it asks you for a duplicate and automatically posts a comment as above, saying "Possible duplicate".  That's the standard, and it is site policy to flag for close if a senior member thinks that it is a duplicate question.  You are entirely correct that there is a big difference between a duplicate question and a question with the same answer as another question.  Such questions are *related* and should be put in the comments, or referenced as part of an answer.

Comment: @Orbling: Thanks for the clarification. As I do not have "close" privileges, I thought I'd link to that question as a reference for those that do. If it's not an exact duplicate - fair enough, but at the very least it serves as a related question as you mentioned.

Comment: @Colin: Yes, it's pretty much the same consideration - whether it is close enough to count as a duplicate is uncertain.  Lucy thinks not, therefore in my book needed a more specific answer.  What you did was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a `JSONobject` in PHP (unless it's some user-defined something or other). There are only arrays or `stdClass` instances generated by [`json_decode`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which can be used with `count`.

It's possible to make an object respond to `count` by having the object implement the [`Countable`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface.

For the sake of completeness, consider the following `count` results:

```
$test = new stdClass;
$test->prop1 = 1;
$test->prop2 = 1;
var_dump(count($test)); // 1

$test = (array) $test;
var_dump(count($test)); // 2

class CountTest {
  public $prop1 = 1;
  public $prop2 = 1;
}

$test = new CountTest;
var_dump(count($test)); // 1

$test = (array) $test;
var_dump(count($test)); // 2

// class implementing Countable
class CountMe implements Countable { 
  protected $myCount = 3; 
  public function count(){ 
     return $this->myCount; 
  }
}
$test = new CountMe;
var_dump(count($test)); // 3
```

Comment: That isn't actually true and I should down vote - but you can fix it.  `json_decode` does return an object (stdClass) by default for objects, unless you pass `true` as the second parameter to it, only then does it return arrays only.

Comment: you had me at these are arrays which are generated by json_decode. thank you!

Comment: thank you orbling - then when I `json_decode` I should pass `true` to get an array I can use in this way? thankyou!

Comment: @Orbling I actually caught that myself after posting and edited between when you saw the problem and I saw your comment :) As always, thanks for the vigilance.

Comment: @LucyWeatherford: Yes, I pretty much always use `json_encode(..., true)` - I cannot think of a reason why the other way would be more useful to be honest, which makes me think it would be better for that to be the default.  An annoyance that all AJAX programmers with PHP have to learn at some point. :-)

Comment: @rdlowrey: Good man - I figured you would catch it, just mentioned it in case others disagreed and downvoted hastily.

Comment: @Orbling For sure -- I try as much as possible to be slow with my righteous downvotes to give people a chance to fix accidents. Looks like I got some karma back, so thanks! I'm with you, though: it seems most people only use `json_decode($json, TRUE)` to get arrays. I always wondered why it wasn't the default option.